# Наследование в php, пространства имен

Tags: php, наследование, namespace

Есть 2 класса:

```
namespace A;

class AClass {
    function create() {
        return new Test(); // по идее тут создается объект класс \A\Test()
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
namespace B;

class BClass extends \A\AClass {
    // мы унаследовали метод create(), но он все равно вернет 
    // нам объект класса \A\Test
    // Как наиболее правильно и гибко реализовать, чтобы метод
    // create в классе BClass возвращал объект класса \B\Test,
    // с минимальным кодом в классе BClass
}
```

При этом важно, не переопределять метод create в классе BClass
Спасибо.

Comment: `return new static()` ?

Comment: @teran как это поможет тут?

Comment: а почему вы решили, что вам вернется A\Test()?

Comment: я вероятно не корректно понял ваш вопрос. скорректируйте, а то у вас приведен код `AClass` и `BClass`, а потом появляется какой-то `Test` в `create()`, а в комментариях во втором опять `BClass`.  У вас в каждом неймспейсе объявлен класс `Test` или что?

Comment: чем не понравился комментарий @teran, [ссылка на доку](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

Comment: @Sergey дак там не экземпляры `AClass` и `BClass` создавать надо, а, видимо, `A\Test` и `B\Test`.

Comment: @teran Да. все правильно. Нужно создавать A\Test B\Test

Comment: @devn а просто добавить `protected $cls = "\A\Test"` и использовать с `return new $this->cls` перекрыв в `$cls = "\B\Test"` не по фен-шую будет, да? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу пару вариантов.

Вариант №1 - задавать имя создаваемого класса в виде `protected` члена класса, перекрывая его в наследниках.

```
namespace A {
    class AClass {

        protected $cls = "\\A\\Test";

        function create() {
            return new $this->cls;
        }
    }

    class Test {}
}

namespace B {
    class BClass extends \A\AClass{
        protected $cls = "\\B\\Test";
    }

    class Test {}
}
```

Вариант №2. Извлекать полное имя класса во время выполнения с помощью `static`, и заменять имя класса, оставляя `namespace`.

```
function create() {
    $cls = preg_replace("/(.+)\\\(\w+?)$/",  "$1\\Test", static::class);
    return new $cls;
}
```